# Pegar objeto json dentro de outro de outro objeto

Tags: php, json, url

Preciso pegar o objeto "online" que está dentro do objeto "players" mais não consigo pegar... só consigo pegar objetos que estão "Na raiz" json onde preciso pegar:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "hostname": "skyminigames.com.br",
    "port": 25565,
    "protocol": "tcp",
    "ping": 126,
    "players": {
        "online": 3376,
        "max": 8500
    },
    "cached": false
}
```

Código que estou usando:

```
<?php 
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://use.gameapis.net/mc/query/players/skyminigames.com.br');
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $obj = json_decode($result);
        echo "$obj->players->online";
?>
```

Comment: Não esqueça de aprovar a resposta do Laerte. Visto que ela está correta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente o `echo` sem aspas duplas:

```
echo $obj->players->online;
```

Comment: Não pode ser usado assim... tem que pegar esses dados da url que estava... pois esses dados atualizão constantemente.

Comment: Consegui, apenas utilizei o echo $obj->players->online; as aspas era o erro acho eu.

Comment: Sim, isso que eu quis dizer, você estava dando echo $obj->players->online como uma string, minha resposta foi você remover as aspas duplas que estavam em volta do echo, eu só deixei o result fixo pra você entender melhor rs.